# Celery: Asynchronously Retrieve Partial Results from Previous Task

Tags: python, celery, etl

I'd like to chain my ETL workflow whereby the Load task can asynchronously stream partial results from the ExtractTransform task without having to wait on ExtractTransform completing. Is that possible with Celery?

Two approaches I was considering:

**Approach 1**

Create an ETLTask where LoadTask (somehow) keeps getting and dequeuing partial results from the ETLTask (essentially separating producer and consumer). I can't tell from the [AsyncResult](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/reference/celery.result.html#celery.result.AsyncResult.result) if that's possible. It sounds like I just want to go down the route of having separate producers and consumers which I'm not sure how to do in Celery.

```
class ExtractTransformTask(Task):

    def long_running_extract_transform(self):
        pass

    def run(self):
        return self.long_running_extract_transform()

class LoadTask(Task):

    def long_running_load(self):
        pass

    def run(self, results):
        self.long_running_load(results)

class ETLTask(Task):

    def run(self):
        et_result = ExtractTransformTask.delay()
        # while et_result PENDING or SUCCESS
        # dequeue current results and load with LoadTask instance
```

**Approach 2**

Extract the source data in chunks and create multiple load tasks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution using **Approach 2**.

```
class ExtractTransformMixin(object):

    def long_running_extract_transform(self, chunkify=False):
        pass

class LoadTask(Task):

    def long_running_load(self):
        pass

    def run(self, results):
        self.long_running_load(results)

class ETLTask(ExtractTransformMixin, Task):

    def run(self):
        load_results = ResultSet([])
        for chunk in long_running_extract_transform(chunkify=True):
            load_results.add(LoadTask().delay(chunk))
        return load_results
```